# Client command not being called Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So the player move command isn't being called on the client(host is fine). The loop is being called and I checked that it is only on the local player. But the actual command isn't being called. The script is on the player prefab which is registered in the network manager. What am I doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MovePlayer : NetworkBehaviour {
    float speed;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    Player player;
    int verticalDir = 0;
    float rot_z;
    int horizontalDir = 0;

    void Start () {
        player = gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
        rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        speed = player.moveSpeed;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (!player.dead && isLocalPlayer)
        {
            // Key Movement
            verticalDir = 0;
            horizontalDir = 0;
            if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            {
                verticalDir += 1;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey("s"))
            {
                verticalDir -= 1;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            {
                horizontalDir -= 1;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            {
                horizontalDir += 1;
            }

            // Mouse Tracking
            Vector3 diff = player.camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
            diff.Normalize();

            rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            CmdMove();

            // Velocity limit
            if (rigidbody.velocity.x > speed)
            {
                rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rigidbody.velocity.y);
            }
            if (rigidbody.velocity.y > speed)
            {
                rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody.velocity.x, speed);
            }
        }
    }
    [Command]
    void CmdMove()
    {
        var locVel = new Vector2(speed * horizontalDir, speed * verticalDir);
        rigidbody.velocity = locVel;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 90);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put some kind of Debug.Log() message before, inside, and after CmdMove() do all three appear or just the ones before and after?

Answer (score 0):

You are using/thinking the `command` wrong! I'll try to explain it short:

- A `[Command]` is invoked by a client but **only** executed on the server!
- A `[ClientRpc]` is invoked by the server but it is executed by **ALL** clients
- A `[Client]` just makes sure this method can only be executed by clients

Now to a code example:

```
// This is called by the client
[Client]
private void DoSomething()
{
    if(!isLocalPlayer) return;

    // Here we call the command on the server passing our gameObject
    CmdDoSomething(gameObject);
}

// This is only executed on the server
// Since the player has a NetworkIdentity the server can identify the correct gameObject we passed
[Command]
private void CmdDoSomething (GameObject player)
{
    // Do stuff that happens only on the server here


    // Now we can send back Information
    // E.g. an int or string again passing the GameObject
    RpcDoSomething(player, "test");
}

// Usually this would be executed by ALL clients
// So we have to check if we are the player who originally called the command
// Again the NetworkIdentity makes sure we can identify the passed GameObject
[ClientRpc]
private void RpcDoSomething (GameObject player, string message)
{
    // For the special case that we are the host (server and client at the same time)
    // we maybe don't want to do something
    // since we probably already did it for ourself before while executing the [Command]
    if(isServer) return;

    // If we are not the one who invoked the command we do nothing
    if(player != gameObject) return;

    // I like to put Debug.Log containing "this" in the end so you can click a Log
    // Entry and see exactly where it came from
    Debug.Log("I received: " + message, this);
}
```

From here you should now be able to implement it for your needs.